# Android secure client to server HTTP requests

Tags: android, admob

I have implemented AdMob's rewarded video ads in my Android application. The problem is, there are no server side callbacks from AdMob to my server so i can securely award credits to the user for watching an ad (not that i know of).

> Server -> Server

I only have a client side callback `onRewarded()`, which using it i need to update my own server.

> Client -> Server

What is the optimal approach that should be used to avoid having users updating their own credits without really watching ads?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?